# Username and usage issue in postgresql psql terminal

Tags: postgresql, terminal, psql

I want to follow the steps shown in the screenshot on the psql screen, but even when I just open the screen, I get a different screen and I get an error every time. There is no website that I haven't visited for days, and there is no video that I haven't watched, but I still haven't been able to reach the result. is there anyone who can help?

[this is my own terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Yyh.png)

[this is what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwt0m.png)

Comment: Please post errors as plain text, not screenshots, whenever possible.

Comment: What keeps you from doing what you want? Just start a command line window and start `psql`

Comment: You need to supply the password.

Answer (score 0):

You are running some kind of wrapper program around psql (maybe a .bat file?).  Find the real psql.exe and run that.  Maybe also figure out what created the bat(?) file and uninstall that, or at least take it out of your PATH.

Comment: It is the shell shortcut installed by the EDB Windows [installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/supported-open-source/postgresql/installer/02_installing_postgresql_with_the_graphical_installation_wizard/). The OP just needs to supply the proper password when prompted. That won't change with using `psql` by itself.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  Is that just for the non-free version? I did recall seeing that somewhere before, but couldn't find it on my Windows system which uses the EDB-provided installer for community PostgreSQL.  I thought the OP was more confused by the presentation rather than the functionality.

Comment: I see it in the free version: Programs --> PostgreSQL 14  --> SQL shell(psql)